Who is responsible for the damage from a tree branch?
Please consider the following hypothetical situation. Paul and Jim both own homes. Their homes are next to each other. Paul has a tree with a big branch on it that extends onto Jim's property.
One night there is very heavy winds and the branch falls down damaging Jim's fence. Is Paul responsible?

Did Paul not properly maintain the tree, making the branch more fragile and likely to break?

@AsheraH:  It shouldn't matter, unless Paul intervened in some way with the tree, otherwise, it should be considered, legally, an "act of god/nature".

canada
Paul is responsible if he was negligent. This will depend on whether he did what was reasonable in the circumstances.
For example, if he knew that previously, branches had fallen, or otherwise should have known of the risk, then he would have an obligation to get at minimum an arborist inspection and depending on the outcome, take more active steps like cut or prune the tree.
See an example case: Reym v. Fox, 2018 BCCRT 63.

the right to cut a branch protruding over a property is not a legal obligation that relieves the respondent of her responsibility to address a potential hazard from the nuisance created by the tree.

Tribunals have also recognized that the tree owner might be liable in nuisance, but have said:

to prove a nuisance when a tree falls onto their property, a person must prove that the tree’s owner knew or should have known the tree was a hazard or at risk of falling

bringing in some negligence principles into the nuisance analysis.

Careful there.  I wouldn't say "Paul was responsible if he was negligent" because you haven't established how responsible a person is for something that is made (and perhaps planted and set) by "GOD" or natural forces.

Also, If the branch hangs over the fence, some jurisdictions might rule that Jim can cut the branch himself -- trees, like children or animals, can't really be owned.

@MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Trees come down in heavy storms all the time. You don't need to consult the Oracle of Delphi to predict that a large tree could cause damage like this. OTOH, we also don't expect everyone to cut down trees that could cause damage during a storm, that's overcompensating. It's a danger we all live with so we can have nice things.

@Barmar:  You also don't need to consult the Oracle that there is a large tree there when you buy the house or erect a fence.  When he bought the house, he could assume that there were risks if trees were nearby.

@MarkRosenblitt-Janssen Depending hon how long ago they bought the house. It could have been a young sapling at the time.

It's complicated
australia
Many, but by no means all, species of native eucalyptus (gum) trees spontaneously drop otherwise healthy limbs even in calm weather, usually in summer. These can be substantial - 250mm (10") diameter and several hundred kg (even more several hundred pounds) are not uncommon. Hence the name "widow-makers", although deaths are fortunately rare; rare enough that the Australian Bureau of Statistics doesn't have a separate category for them. They also have relatively shallow roots for their height, so they tend to fall over in strong winds.
Some jurisdictions rely on common law tort remedies (which are often complex and fact-dependent), and others have specific statutes dealing with neighbour disputes, trees, or both.
In the situation you describe, the tree-owing neighbour would not generally be held liable for negligence as that requires some failure on their part in their duty. That is, there must be some act or omission that can be pointed to as something they did or did not do that they should not have done or done. Respectively.
Some acts or omissions that could apply are if the neighbour selected and planted an inappropriate tree species, if the tree was obviously unhealthy to a layperson, if the tree was obviously dead, if the tree had dropped limbs before, or if concerns about the tree had been raised in the past.
However, AFAIK, all local governments in Australia have rules that limit the pruning or removal of certain trees without a permit. So, the neighbour's obligation would only be to seek a permit and do whatever work the council allowed. If the permit was refused, it is possible (and has been the case in the past) that the local government was negligent and, therefore, liable, particularly if they made their decision without engaging the services of a qualified arborist.

france
I should note right at the outset that when it comes to such disputes, "Paul" and "Jim" are usually replaced by "Paul’s insurance company" and "Jim’s insurance company". For the vast majority (>99%) of such disputes, Paul and Jim fill out their insurance’s paperwork and those companies settle without filing anything in court.
The general rule of civil liability is that Paul is liable if:

Jim suffered a damage,
Paul is at fault (for acting or failing to act),
and Jim’s damage was caused by Paul’s fault.

Damage
That one is easy. Jim’s fence needs repairs. Paul might dispute the amount but it is nonzero.
Fault
Fault is usually established by the violation of an applicable contract or statute. Paul and Jim might be bound by HoA-type regulations, municipal ordnances, and the like; I will assume this is not the case. Thus, we turn to articles 671 to 673 of the civil code:

[671] Il n'est permis d'avoir des arbres, arbrisseaux et arbustes près de la limite de la propriété voisine qu'à la distance prescrite par les règlements particuliers actuellement existants, ou par des usages constants et reconnus et, à défaut de règlements et usages, qu'à la distance de deux mètres de la ligne séparative des deux héritages pour les plantations dont la hauteur dépasse deux mètres, et à la distance d'un demi-mètre pour les autres plantations.
Les arbres, arbustes et arbrisseaux de toute espèce peuvent être plantés en espaliers, de chaque côté du mur séparatif, sans que l'on soit tenu d'observer aucune distance, mais ils ne pourront dépasser la crête du mur. (...)
[672] Le voisin peut exiger que les arbres, arbrisseaux et arbustes, plantés à une distance moindre que la distance légale, soient arrachés ou réduits à la hauteur déterminée dans l'article précédent, à moins qu'il n'y ait titre, destination du père de famille ou prescription trentenaire. (...)
[673] Celui sur la propriété duquel avancent les branches des arbres, arbustes et arbrisseaux du voisin peut contraindre celui-ci à les couper. (...)


[671] Trees and woody plants must be separated from the limits of the neighboring property by a distance prescribed by current special rules, or by constant and admitted custom. Failing the existence of such rules or customs, the distance is set to two meters for plant rising more than two meters, and half a meter otherwise.
Trees and woody plants might be planted in espalier [= grown against the wall], on either side of the separation wall, with no such distance; they may not be grown above the wall height. (...)
[672] The neighbor may demand that trees and woody plants that [do not comply with 671] be removed or shortened by the owner, unless [any of the following apply: the owner has a written contract allowing them to keep them, the trees were planted before the property was divided which caused the lack of distance, the trees have been in violation of 671 for at least thirty years without legal action been brought]. (...)
[673] When branches from trees and woody plants owned by one person advance above another person’s estate, the latter may force the latter to cut them. (...)

(US readers might notice a scent of adverse possession doctrine.)
There are more general statutes prohibiting causing abnormal troubles to one’s neighbor etc. I would expect those to not be applicable due to a contrario reasoning: the statute goes into much detail about certain duties; had other similarly specific duties in the same field been desired by the legislator, they would have been written down; but they were not.
Hence, fault is somewhat easy to establish as a legal matter (though there might be difficulties with respect to evidence if facts are contested). If Jim had previously requested that the branch be cut under 673, or if the tree was within two meters of the line while none of the exceptions apply, then Paul is at fault. Conversely, if the tree was more than two meters away and Jim never requested that the branch be cut, Paul is not at fault. (Jim owns fruit that falls from the branch into his garden - I cut out that part from 673 but yes, the code is that specific. Jim cannot eat the fruit and then complain when the branch falls, can he?)
Causation
The problem here is that French causation doctrine is a mess. (See, among other voluminous law review articles: Définition de la causalité en droit français, Christophe Quézel-Ambrunaz, 2010). There is no statutory definition, so the jurisprudence is really case-by-case with no clear direction.
What is decently well-established is that, when a given damage results from the combined faulty actions of several actors, all those actors are jointly liable for the final damage (see for instance 27 mars 2003, Cour de cassation, Pourvoi n° 01-00.850). Here, there is only one actor that can be held legally responsible (Paul), so he cannot be found 10% or 20% responsible of the damage: it is all or nothing.
But did his actions contribute to the damage? After all, if the winds were extraordinarily strong, maybe the tempest is 100% responsible?
To take the extreme cases, if the winds had carried the branch over Jim’s very large garden, and damaged the fence on the other side (hundreds of meters from the tree), surely that might have happened regardless of whether the branch was one meter in or out of the garden, and Paul is not liable. In the other extreme, a camera happened to record the moment when the branch fell, and the film shows it falling straight down onto the fence with no deviation in the wind’s direction - in that case Paul is liable.
In most circumstances, I would expect Paul would need to pay (since prima facie his negligence would have contributed to the damage, and he will have the utmost difficulties producing evidence otherwise) unless the heavy winds were deemed a "natural catastrophe". This is an administrative determination that the weather event was so extreme as to overwhelm usual precautions (i.e. nobody is liable), which triggers certain insurance payouts - in particular Jim’s insurance (if he subscribed the appropriate contract) will have to pay out (and will have no recourse against Paul).

It depends on the specific statutes and case law of the specific state wherein Jim and Paul reside. But generally, the tree is the property of Paul, as the tree is rooted on his land; however, any limbs extending over the property line into Jim's property can lawfully be trimmed by Jim up to Paul's property line without Paul's consent (and if Jim is truly savvy, he'll hire a professional arborist to do any such trimming).
Thus, given that Jim had the legal right to trim back such branches extending over his property without Paul's consent, thereby mitigating any risk from those overreaching branches, any damages caused to Jim's property by such overreaching limbs are entirely Jim's problem, not Paul's, even if the overreaching limb broke on Paul's side of the property line. Jim had every opportunity to trim back the overreaching branches, and that those branches might fall onto and damage his property is a foreseeable risk.
Not legal advice, yet: Hire a licensed local arborist, as they are going to be able to tell you what your legal rights are in your locality; and having hired such an expert will tend to help out should one get hauled into court.

The question is tagged United States. You gave a Canadian answer. Also, notice how the very first sentence I gave began "It depends..." and then proceeded to give the answer that would apply to most U.S. states, while also couching that OP should consult with a local professional. You guys are nice up there, and all, with your Ryan Reynolds and Celine Dion, but you still missed some important contextual clues that OP put on their question.

Yes, depending on whether the locality follows the Massachusetts rule or the Virginia rule. Under the latter rule, P can cut back invasive branches and limbs up to the property line. Under the Mass. rule, there is no remedy. FindLaw.com has a whole article about it: https://www.findlaw.com/realestate/neighbors/conflicts-involving-trees-and-neighbors.html

Oh, wait, I just noticed I have the names backwards.... Oops. I'll edit (with notations). Anyway, the linked article makes no distinction on where the fallen branch was before it fell, so my reading of that turns on where it hangs before it falls. If it hangs over Paul's property and is looking in rough shape, and then falls onto J's property, then Paul would definitely be liable. But that's not the question above, which is about a branch already overhanging the property line into Jim's property, which Jim had every right to engage in self-help on his side of the line.

Assumption of risk is a thing that exists. If I'm Paul, that's my first go-to. If it's a perfectly healthy branch, then I have no reason to foresee it falling in a windstorm; therefore, force majeure/act of God, for which I'm not liable. In any other scenario, Jim could cut it back at any time yet chose to assume the risk of not doing so. His loss, for which I'm not liable.

You're asking me to support a bunch of points that weren't raised in the initial question. I'm answering the question OP asked, not playing a game of hide the ball with myself, or you, for that matter. I have better uses of my time.

@Jen Trees are a result of a natural process, and in many situations (a wooded lot), one cannot reasonably inspect or trim every single branch at every time. Therefore, laws are specific to trees, and do not behave as if it's generally the landowner's responsibility. You cannot compare tree liability to, say, an automobile.

In California, the property owner is responsible for abating hazardous conditions in and around his property, including trees — even trees planted on public property immediately in front of his house!  If they fail to do so, yes, they are liable for any harm that results.  I assume the law is similar in other states.
I once had a neighbor whose tree had a limb actually leaning against my house. The owner was herself a real-estate agent and she was preparing to sell the property, and I wanted to make sure that the liability was duly disclosed to the buyers. I called her and the conversation went something like this:
“I need you to either cut the limb or at least disclose to the buyers so that I am not the bearer of the bad news to my new neighbors.”
“I’m an old lady [she was 60]. I can’t be cutting trees. I have a bad back. I’m in constant pain.”
“I am sorry to hear that. I am not asking you personally scale the tree, but you need to call a tree-surgeon. Or just disclose it to the new owners, and we’ll take it up with them.”
“I’m wracked with pain!”
The conversation continued along those lines until I excused myself and called her “broker”, the senior agent in her office. I explained the situation.
“I don’t see how that is our problem,” she told me.
“One of your agents is selling her house and not fully disclosing a known, serious liability issue. That is a violation of California real-estate law, as I am sure you know.”
“It may be but she is selling the property on her own. Nothing to do with us.”
“Well, that excuse might fly in court. I’m not a lawyer myself, nor am I a real-estate broker, but if I were a real-estate broker, I would talk to a lawyer before I would put my broker’s license in danger. You’re a big company, you have lawyers on retainer. Why don’t you call them and call me back.”
She called back 10 minutes later with a solution: she was going to have my neighbor cut down all the trees on the property. “Just the one limb will be fine, thanks,” I explained.

I don't understand the solution. I thought the lady was the neighbor. Who is the neighbor who's going to cut down the trees?

@Barmar — The lady was the current neighbor, but she was selling the house, so I would have to deal with the new neighbor.  Technically, it wasn’t my problem: if she failed to disclose an issue, it was a civil problem between her and the buyer.  I just didn’t want to stir up a problem with my  new neighbor, who might be there for years.
